# How to reliably check Steam Web API Status?

Tags: php, steam-web-api

i'm working with php and the Steam Web Api so if the API is offline all the app go incredibly buggy. Because of that i'm trying to find a way to reliably check Steam Web API Status (No STEAM Status itself, only Steam Web API).

I tried to ping the web API IP Address given by Valve (208.64.202.0) but i can't ping it even if it's online.

EDIT: Still got no clue how to do it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, but I have a Google Apps Script that periodically pulls info from the steam API, and I just do a try/catch for a server 200 response, and if I don't get a 200 response code, It's down/not returning data. Is there a reason you're not doing something similar?

Comment: I'll try to do that in php.